# Confusion about user story in project requirement document

Tags: agile, user-stories

I've user story section in my project requirement document.
User story goes like this,

`As a user I want to check in to the venue`

and another one,

`As a user if I already checked in then check in button should be hidden`

I am going in the right direction with this or I should rethink this stories?

Comment: Adding some context with "so that..." would probably provide implementation guidance to your stories.

Comment: "project requirement document"?? Surely you mean product backlog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you writing Acceptance Criteria along with you User Stories, if not then it might be a good time for you to start writing them. From the example you gave, I believe that

> then check in button should be hidden

becomes **one of the acceptance test** of the first story:

> As a user I want to check in to the venue [so that ....]

Each acceptance test represents some expected result from the system. A story will not be considered complete / done unless it fulfills all of the acceptance criteria of that story.

Some useful links to explore more about acceptance tests:

- [Acceptance Tests in Scrum](http://implementingagile.blogspot.com/2011/05/acceptance-tests-in-scrum.html)
- [User stories: a beginner’s guide to acceptance criteria](http://www.boost.co.nz/blog/agile/acceptance-criteria/)
- [Acceptance testing](http://guide.agilealliance.org/guide/acceptance.html)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer that Aziz gave, I would ask whether your project truly has a single kind of user or if there are aspects that differentiate your users. If you do have more than one type of user, it is important to identify which one you are writing the story for (even if it feels like it should be obvious). In other words, instead of saying "as a user", you might say "as an anonymous user" or "as a registered user". We often take this a step further and develop [pragmatic personas](http://www.stickyminds.com/sitewide.asp?Function=edetail&ObjectType=COL&ObjectId=15793) for use in our stories.

Answer (score 1):

User Stories should follow this format.

```
As a (role) - This can be an end user or a business proxy

I want - A description of what needs to be done

So that - the definition of the value
```

Acceptance criteria is then required so you know when you are done. This can be a bullets list, like you have, or context specification style (part of BDD - Business Driven Development).

The one major bit of advise I have is do not write the User Stories on your own. Creating a backlog using User Stories is a collaborative technique. Without this, you will be missing the point and main advantage of this approach. Emergent requirements and [valuing customer collaboration over contract negotiation](http://agilemanifesto.org/).

If you would like to know more I  suggest reading Mike Cohn's User Stories Applied.